# Finding word patterns in a dictionary, high performance

Tags: c++, regex, dictionary, unordered-map

I need to build some sort of dictionary that in addition contains the word-frequencies with which each word occurs in the language. Normally, this would be implemented using a std::unordered_map right? Now here's the catch... I want to find all words and their frequencies that conform to some regular expression, and performance is my biggest concern.

I don't think I will be able to avoid iterating over a range of elements and element-wise check if they match the pattern. Therefore, I thought it might be clever to use a pair of vectors instead of a map:

```
using namespace std;
typedef vector<pair<string, double>> Dictionary
vector<Dictionary::const_iterator> index;
Dictionary dict;
...
for_each(index['d'], index['e'], DoSomething);
```

This would allow me to iterate effectively over all words that start with, in this case, a 'd'. Of course, this only helps if I already know the first letter of my regex which often will not be the case I presume. Also, if I already know the entire word without any uncertainties and just want to look up its frequency, I'd have to iterate through the entire section until I find it. A map would allow me to look it up faster. E.g. when looking for the word 'deer'

```
Dictionary::const_iterator it = 
    find_if(index['d'], index['e'], []    // Lambda
        (pair<string, double> const &pr)
        {
           return pr.first == "deer";
        });
```

Not optimal at all! A solution might be to use different implementations of the dictionary for different situations, and even though memory is no big concern, this seems like a silly workaround.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines you were thinking of, an 
`std::vector<std::pair<boost::regex, int> >` would probably be
most efficient; you iterate trying to find a match.

A much better solution, if you're willing to do the work, would
be to implement your own regular expression class, *without*
capture (the `(...)` operator in most regular expressions).
Without capture, it's fairly easy to convert the regular
expression to a pure DFA, *and* it is possible to *or* regular
expressions, with each regular expression returning a different
accept code.  (This is the way my own regular expression class
works.  For most applications, it's not nearly as flexible as
that of Boost, because it doesn't support capture.  But it does
allow things like:

```
RegularExpression t1( expr1", 0 );
RegularExpression t2( expr2", 1 );
//  ...
RegularExpression t = t1 | t2 /* | t3 | t4 | ... */ ;
```

When matching, it will return 0 if expr1 matches, 1 if expr2
matches, etc.; you can then use the match id as an index into
a vector of int.  (It returns -1 if there is no match.)

Done this way, the search time is linear with respect to the
length of the input.  Regardless of the number of expressions
you're trying to match.  (My RegularExpression class was
designed over 20 years ago, for generating compiler
front ends.  About 15 years ago, I redid it to handle UTF-8 as
input.)

For many years, the code was available on the web, but I've not
got a web page at present, so unless someone has kept an old
copy, it isn't.  I would be happy to send it to you, but be
warned that the library hasn't been maintained for a while, so
it may not be trivial to get it to compile with a modern
compiler.  (It was originally written in pre-standard C++, and
still contains a number of work-arounds to get it to compile
with things like Sun CC 4.x.)

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of information! Good information though... really appreciate it! I think writing a DFA should be fairly doable, but if you don't mind me asking for some additional explanation: What is the purpose of the `vector<int>` that you mention (which is indexed by the match-ID)? Furthermore, how does the `vector<pair<RegularExpression, int>>` fit in? Where is my frequency information (double's) stored now? Excuse me if these are trivialities, I'm new to this area of expertise.

Comment: @user1428839 The `vector<int>` was simply to collect the counts; all `RegularExpression` (at least in my implementation) will do is return an `int`: -1 if no match, otherwise the second argument to its constructor.  And it was a `vector<pair<boost::regex, int> >`; the alternative using a widely available regular expression class.  As for the rest, parsing a regular expression to build a DFA is a significant amount of work.  I did it because I needed it at the time.  (On the other hand, my code will work with an InputIterator, and it _is_ fast.)

Comment: @jamer-kanze Hm okay. I only need to parse very simple expressions that need not be general at all so in my case it might be less work but I see your point. Thanks!

Comment: @user1428839 For very simple, fixed expressions, I've worked out the DFA by hand.  I thought you'd be getting the patterns as user input or something.

Comment: Actually, I need to assign a value to partial solutions of a decryption to estimate the usefulness of continuing the decryption process. If the partial solution is "T.ecows.ysm.o" (Thecowsaysmoo), it should keep going whereas "Hna.sadd.cc.a" doesn't yield anything. Therefore I need to match pieces of such strings to a dictionary but these pieces are mostly words with some letters missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your best choice would be to use a Finite Satae Transducer like http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/projekte/gramotron/SOFTWARE/SFST.html .

The map will, as you said, use up much space.

You could see the transducer as one big regex (a Regex is a compiled automaton).

Comment: One big regex is the solution: you could use something like `boost::regex m( "(" + expr1 + ")|(" + expr2 + ")... )`, but you'd still have to iterator over the submatches, to determine which one matched.  And while a true regular expression compiles to a DFA, once you add capture, I don't think it does; all of the implementations I'm familiar with use an NFA, and most use backtracking, which means that the complexity is influenced by the complexity of the expression being matches.